# troubleshoot between plugin and application server?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

the request from ihs is passed to plugin then to the application server and server received it.there is no cluster environment here.the server is up and running fine.But the response is not going back to plugin.how to troubleshoot?

Comment: step 0 here is to review your http_plugin.log.  Please update the question with the basics of the logging!

Answer (score 1):

(I would have made this a comment, but I don't have enough rep points).

You may need to engage IBM WebSphere Support to assist with this, but typically, for that type of issue, you would need to trace both sides of the connection (IHS plugin and WebSphere). Specifically,

- Set LogLevel="Trace" in the plugin-cfg.xml
- Set the following trace spec on the AppServer:

*=info:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all:HTTPChannel=all:GenericBNF=all:TCPChannel=all

Reproducing the failure and reviewing the http_plugin.log and trace.log may provide some clues.

Do you receive some type of error in the browser? timeout? Is there anything (firewall, proxy) sitting between the IHS server and WebSphere AppServer?

Comment: Yes the firewall exists between them.but in browser  nothing error is not showing

Comment: Make sure the firewall allows traffic from the IHS/plugin machine to the app server machine's webcontainer port (e.g. 9080 / 9443). You can also try hitting the App server directly from the browser (bypassing the IHS/plugin) as a test. For example: http://<your_appserver>:9080/your_app. If that works, then may be that the plugin is unable to connect to the app server (maybe due to firewall). There are many possibilities.. so likely would need to enable the tracing I mentioned and engage IBM Support if you need help reviewing the logs.

Comment: Thanx @brandon for u r sugestion

Answer (score 0):

It could be DNS problem with your WebSphere server. Can you please let us know about your IHS and plugin. Is it installed on same server where WebSphere is or on different server? If IHS and plugin is on different server just check that WebSphere server is able to resolve the IP address of IHS server using hostname. If not try to update host file with IP and hostname of your IHS server. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Does the client or the plugin not getting the response?  Will that the request result in secure connection (i.e HTTPS/SSL...)?

The WAS server should extract most of the ports correctly if IHS/plugin is used in between.  If using different webServer/load balancer(LB), the WAS server may not extract the listerning ports on the webServer/LB correctly.

You can take a look at the sample setting in PK55330 where a different web server is used in place of the IHS.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK55330

Regards,